# How can I examine local values of a function within the debugger?

Tags: f#

How can I examine local values of a function within the debugger?

I'm trying to wrap my head around currying and functional composition.

In doing so, I would like to leverage the debugger.
However, I am unable to examine the values for "a" and "b" within the add function when using the debugger.

```
let add a b = 
        a + b;; // set a breakpoint here

let addTen = add 10;;
let result = addTen 20;;
```

I even tried printing values using the following:

```
let add a b = 
    printfn "a equals: %a and b equals: %b" a b
    a + b
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is from a script file, you can't easily debug F# scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9081371/126014

Comment: Currently it's an FS file. So I can just throw the logic into a script file and use the debugger to examine local values within a function? I'm curious why I can't have this behavior in a standard FS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the version using `printfn` is that the placeholders are wrong. `%a` is a general format specifier that requires *two* arguments, and `%b` expects a `bool`.

Try changing the function to this:

```
let inline add a b = 
    printfn "a equals: %A and b equals: %A" a b
    a + b
```

Now it'll print the 'debug' text when all arguments are applied:

```
> let addTen = add 10;;

val addTen : (int -> int)

> let result = addTen 20;;
a equals: 10 and b equals: 20

val result : int = 30
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. What value does "inline" provide?

Comment: Yea, I looked at it before asking and could only come up with performance. I wasn't sure if using an inline was significant or not.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Try removing the `inline` keyword. If you do, the compiler will default to interpret the type of the function to only work on `int`. With `inline`, it works with any type on which `+` is defined.